# Drawing Three Circles, Storing the Data, and Comparing them

Tags: java, comparison, draw

First year java student, going on about 8 weeks of experience so far. So, I need to create three circles and display them with a drawing panel. Then I need to create static method that should have parameters for the radiuses of two circles (two parameters), and the method should return -1 if the first circle is smaller, return 0 if the two circles have the same size, or return 1 if the first circle is larger.  Based on the return value from this method, the main method should print a line of output like:

The green circle is smaller than the red circle.

I've got the circles drawn, but I don't know how to store that value from the user and then compare them. Any help would be great. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Circles {
  public static final Scanner CONSOLE=new Scanner(System.in);

  //prompt user
  public static int promptForInt(String prompt) {
    System.out.print(prompt);
    return CONSOLE.nextInt();
  }

  //Static method w/ parameters for the radiuses of red circle
  public static int redCircle(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    int radius = promptForInt("Please enter the raidus of the red circle: ");
    int x = promptForInt("Please enter the x-coordinate of the red circle: ");
    int y= promptForInt("Please enter the y-coordinate of the red circle: ");
    g.fillOval(0+x, 0+y, radius*2, radius*2);
  }

  //Static method w/ parameters for the radiuses of the green circle
  public static void greenCircle(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    int radius = promptForInt("Please enter the raidus of the green circle: ");
    int x = promptForInt("Please enter the x-coordinate of the green circle: ");
    int y= promptForInt("Please enter the y-coordinate of the green circle: ");
    g.fillOval(0+x, 0+y, radius*2, radius*2);
  }

  //Static method w/ parameters for the radiuses of the green circle
  public static void blueCircle(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    int radius = promptForInt("Please enter the raidus of the blue circle: ");
    int x = promptForInt("Please enter the x-coordinate of the blue circle: ");
    int y= promptForInt("Please enter the y-coordinate of the blue circle: ");
    g.fillOval(0+x, 0+y, radius*2, radius*2);
  }

  //compares two circles
  public static void compareCircles(int r1, int r2){
    return r1-r2;

  }

  //exe starts here
  public static void main(String [] args){
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(400,300);
    Graphics g =  panel.getGraphics();

    System.out.println("Lab 5 written by me.\n"); 
    redCircle(g);
    greenCircle(g);
    blueCircle(g);
  }
}
```

Edited to add in the DrawPanel by the request of MadProgrammer

```
/*
Stuart Reges and Marty Stepp
February 24, 2007
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2010 (no anti-alias, repaint on sleep)
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2012 (track mouse clicks and movement)
Changes by Tom Bylander in 2013 (fix bug in tracking mouse clicks)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (getters for width and height)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (addKeyListener added)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2014 (catch exception on default close so that it works in an applet)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2015 (buffer key events)
Changes by S. Robbins   in 2015 (show mouse status by default is off)

The DrawingPanel class provides a simple interface for drawing persistent
images using a Graphics object.  An internal BufferedImage object is used
to keep track of what has been drawn.  A client of the class simply
constructs a DrawingPanel of a particular size and then draws on it with
the Graphics object, setting the background color if they so choose.

To ensure that the image is always displayed, a timer calls repaint at
regular intervals.
*/

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DrawingPanel implements ActionListener {
 private static final String versionMessage = 
    "Drawing Panel version 1.1, January 25, 2015";
 private static final int DELAY = 100;  // delay between repaints in millis
 private static final boolean PRETTY = false;  // true to anti-alias
 private static boolean showStatus = false;
 private static final int MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE = 10;

 private int width, height;    // dimensions of window frame
 private JFrame frame;         // overall window frame
 private JPanel panel;         // overall drawing surface
 private BufferedImage image;  // remembers drawing commands
 private Graphics2D g2;        // graphics context for painting
 private JLabel statusBar;     // status bar showing mouse position
 private volatile MouseEvent click;     // stores the last mouse click
 private volatile boolean pressed;      // true if the mouse is pressed
 private volatile MouseEvent move;      // stores the position of the mouse
 private ArrayList<KeyInfo> keys;

 // construct a drawing panel of given width and height enclosed in a window
 public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
   this.width = width;
   this.height = height;
   keys = new ArrayList<KeyInfo>();
   image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

   statusBar = new JLabel(" ");
   statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
   statusBar.setText(versionMessage);

   panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
   panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
   panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));

   click = null;
   move = null;
   pressed = false;

   // listen to mouse movement
   MouseInputAdapter listener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
     public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = false;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("moved (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("pressed (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
       pressed = true;
       move = e;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("dragged (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
       click = e;
       pressed = false;
       if (showStatus)
          statusBar.setText("released (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
     }

     public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
//       System.out.println("mouse entered");
       panel.requestFocus();
     }

   };
   panel.addMouseListener(listener);
   panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);
   new DrawingPanelKeyListener();

   g2 = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
   g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
   if (PRETTY) {
     g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.1f));
   }

   frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel");
   frame.setResizable(false);
   try {
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // so that this works in an applet
   } catch (Exception e) {}
   frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
   frame.getContentPane().add(statusBar, "South");
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
   toFront();
   frame.requestFocus();

   // repaint timer so that the screen will update
   new Timer(DELAY, this).start();
 }

 public void showMouseStatus(boolean f) {
   showStatus = f;
 }

 public void addKeyListener(KeyListener listener) {
   panel.addKeyListener(listener);
   panel.requestFocus();
 }

 // used for an internal timer that keeps repainting
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   panel.repaint();
 }

 // obtain the Graphics object to draw on the panel
 public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
   return g2;
 }

 // set the background color of the drawing panel
 public void setBackground(Color c) {
   panel.setBackground(c);
 }

 // show or hide the drawing panel on the screen
 public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
   frame.setVisible(visible);
 }

 // makes the program pause for the given amount of time,
 // allowing for animation
 public void sleep(int millis) {
   panel.repaint();
   try {
     Thread.sleep(millis);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 }

 // close the drawing panel
 public void close() {
   frame.dispose();
 }

 // makes drawing panel become the frontmost window on the screen
 public void toFront() {
   frame.toFront();
 }

 // return panel width
 public int getWidth() {
    return width;
 }

 // return panel height
 public int getHeight() {
    return height;
 }

 // return the X position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseX() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the mouse or -1
 public int getMouseY() {
   if (move == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return move.getY();
   }
 }

 // return the X position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickX() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getX();
   }
 }

 // return the Y position of the last click or -1
 public int getClickY() {
   if (click == null) {
     return -1;
   } else {
     return click.getY();
   }
 }

 // return true if a mouse button is pressed
 public boolean mousePressed() {
   return pressed;
 }

 public synchronized int getKeyCode() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyCode;
 }

  public synchronized char getKeyChar() {
   if (keys.size() == 0)
     return 0;
   return keys.remove(0).keyChar;
 }

  public synchronized int getKeysSize() {
    return keys.size();
  }

 private synchronized void insertKeyData(char c, int code) {
   keys.add(new KeyInfo(c,code));
   if (keys.size() > MAX_KEY_BUF_SIZE) {
     keys.remove(0);
//     System.out.println("Dropped key");
   }
 }

 private class KeyInfo {
   public int keyCode;
   public char keyChar;

   public KeyInfo(char keyChar, int keyCode) {
     this.keyCode = keyCode;
     this.keyChar = keyChar;
   }
 }

 private class DrawingPanelKeyListener implements KeyListener {

   int repeatCount = 0;

   public DrawingPanelKeyListener() {
     panel.addKeyListener(this);
     panel.requestFocus();
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
//     System.out.println("key pressed");
     repeatCount++;
     if ((repeatCount == 1) || (getKeysSize() < 2))
        insertKeyData(event.getKeyChar(),event.getKeyCode());
   }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
     repeatCount = 0;
   }

 }

}
```

Comment: `Graphics g =  panel.getGraphics();` is NOT how custom painting works in Swing - see [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details (and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting actually works).  Don't mix UI and console based programming together, this is a bad idea as may UI's won't open a console for the user

Comment: First time I've heard the name Swing, to be honest. Our professor had us download a java file named DrawingPanel that we import to create graphics. It's how we've done everything so far.

Comment: If you can post the `DrawPanel`, it might make it easier to make suggestions

Comment: @MadProgrammer since `DrawPanel` uses composition and not inheritance, it's immposible to override `paintComponent()`.

Comment: @MouseEvent No it's not, it's just a pain to fix and is a particularly horrible way to achieve the results :P

Answer (score 0):

Create an own class Circle, store the position of the Circles each in one instance of Circle and save those Circles to variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare radiuses (or radii), all other info are irrelevant:

```
public static int compareCircles(int r1, int r2){
    return r1 - r2;      
}
```

This is the conventional way of comparing, even if it doesn't return -1/0/1.
You can still tinker around if you really want these return values.

Comment: I can argue and win the case for not using -1/0/1, that's easy. Where would I declare the method compareCircles, and how will I have the stored radii from redCircle, blueCircle, etc?

Comment: Since all your code is static, you'll have to save them in a global variable at your drawing methods, so it's accessible in the main.

Comment: So would I need to do a return int radius at the end of say, redCircle? Something like:

`public static int redCircle(Graphics g){
....
return radius; }`

Comment: @JBGriffin Yes, a return statement is even a better approach than mine - to use a global variable.